# Using an instance on form "doesn't raise an HttpResponse object" even though the object exists in the database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to fetch forms for floorplans for individual property's.  I can check that the object exists in the database, but when I try to create a form with an instance of it I receive this error:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/balrog911/Desktop/mvp/mvp_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  130.                                  % (callback.__module__, view_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /dashboard-property/253/
Exception Value: The view properties.views.dashboard_single_property didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

My models.py:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text="This is the name that will display on your profile")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='properties/', null=True, blank=True)    
    options=(('House', 'House'),('Condo','Condo'),('Apartment','Apartment')) 
    rental_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=options, default='Apartment')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    lng = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    coordinates =models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=501)
    active = models.BooleanField(default= True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self):
        super(Property, self).save()
        max_length = Property._meta.get_field('slug').max_length
        slug_name = slugify(self.name)
        self.slug = '%s-%d' % (slug_name, self.id)  
        self.coordinates = geo_lat_lng(self.address)
        self.lat = self.coordinates[0]
        self.lng = self.coordinates[1]
        super(Property, self).save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s-%s-%s' % (self.id, self.name, self.address)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single_property", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def get_dashboard_url(self):
        return reverse("dashboard_single_property", kwargs={"id": self.id})

class FloorPlan(models.Model):
    property_name = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='property_name')
    floor_plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    numbers = (('0','0'),('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5'),('6+','6+'),)
    bedrooms = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=numbers)
    bathrooms = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=numbers)
    sqft = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    min_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    max_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    availability = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Use mm/dd/yyyy format')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='floor_plans/', null=True, blank=True)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.property_name)
```

My views.py:

```
def dashboard_single_property(request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        try:
            single_property = Property.objects.get(id=id)
            user_properties = Property.objects.filter(user=user)
            if single_property in user_properties:
                user_property = Property.objects.get(id=id)
                #Beginning of Pet Policy Instances 
                user_floor_plan = FloorPlan.objects.select_related('Property').filter(property_name=user_property)
                if user_floor_plan:
                    print user_floor_plan
                    plans = user_floor_plan.count()
                    plans = plans + 1
                    FloorPlanFormset = inlineformset_factory(Property, FloorPlan, extra=plans)
                    formset_floor_plan = FloorPlanFormset(instance=user_floor_plan)
                    print "formset_floor_plan is True"
                else:
                    floor_plan_form = FloorPlanForm(request.POST or None)
                    formset_floor_plan = False
                    print 'formset is %s' % (formset_floor_plan)
                #End
                #Beginning of Pet Policy Instances 
                user_pet_policy = PetPolicy.objects.select_related('Property').filter(property_name=user_property)
                print user_pet_policy
                if user_pet_policy:
                    print user_pet_policy
                    #pet_policy_form = PetPolicyForm(request.POST or None, instance=user_pet_policy)
                    pet_policy_form = PetPolicyForm(request.POST or None)
                else:
                    pet_policy_form = PetPolicyForm(request.POST or None)
                #End
                basic_form = PropertyForm(request.POST or None, instance=user_property)
                context = {
                'user_property': user_property,
                'basic_form': basic_form,
                'floor_plan_form': floor_plan_form,
                'formset_floor_plan': formset_floor_plan,
                'pet_policy_form': pet_policy_form,
                }
                template = 'dashboard/dashboard_single_property.html'
                return render(request, template, context)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
            #raise Http404
            print "whoops"
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
```

**EDIT:** Took Vishen's tip to make sure the error was raised, updated the views and now I'm getting this error.  Here's the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/dashboard-property/253/

Django Version: 1.7.4
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'base',
 'properties',
 'renters',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'crispy_forms',
 'datetimewidget',
 'djrill',
 'import_export',
 'multiselectfield')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/balrog911/Desktop/mvp/mvp_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/balrog911/Desktop/mvp/mvp_1_live/src/properties/views.py" in dashboard_single_property
  82.             raise e

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dashboard-property/253/
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

**EDIT:**
Per Vishen's suggestion, removed the try statement to see if the error would be made more clear.  It looks like the issues is with line 51:

```
formset_floor_plan = FloorPlanFormset(instance=user_floor_plan)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/balrog911/Desktop/mvp/mvp_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/balrog911/Desktop/mvp/mvp_1_live/src/properties/views.py" in dashboard_single_property
  51.                 formset_floor_plan = FloorPlanFormset(instance=user_floor_plan)
File "/Users/balrog911/Desktop/mvp/mvp_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  855.         if self.instance.pk is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dashboard-property/253/
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if an `Exception` gets raised inside the `try` statement, you catch it, print "whoops" and then the function ends without returning anything; where it needs to return an `HttpResponse`. There is a few ways to solve this, but I suggest making the `except` the following

```
except Exception as e:
    raise e # This will throw a 500
```

I am guessing that something in the `try` statement is error'ing but you are silencing it. But you should throw the error so you can see and fix whatever is breaking.

Comment: Thank you!  Added this and added the raised error in the post.

Comment: Sure, just added the full traceback.  Unless there's something else I should add?

Comment: Okay so your problem is `Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'`. I can't see where this is happening, Django should usually show you where, not sure why it isn't. But I can't see anything in the code you posted, so you may have to spend some time debugging it.

Comment: Actually, I think my suggestion has broken where the problem is, maybe try removing the try statement altogether, and that might show you where they actual error is happening.

Comment: Removed the try statement, added the new traceback error to the post.

Comment: So the error is happening `formset_floor_plan = FloorPlanFormset(instance=user_floor_plan)` but it is because `user_floor_plan = FloorPlan.objects.select_related('Property').filter(property_name=user_property)` is returning a queryset(`.filter()`) and not an object (`.get()`). I am not sure what you actually want here, but make sure `user_floor_plan` is an instance of `FloorPlan`.

Comment: I used filter because a property may have multiple floorplans.  When I use

'user_floor_plan = FloorPlan.objects.filter(property_name=user_property)'

I get the same error.  Which I thought would be an instance of FloorPlan.

Comment: A `.filter()` will always return a list, where as a `.get()` will return a single object. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something for the first if statement. You are getting that error because nothing is being returned if the statement is valid.

```
def dashboard_single_property(request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        try:
            single_property = Property.objects.get(id=id)
            user_properties = Property.objects.filter(user=user)
            if single_property in user_properties:
                user_property = Property.objects.get(id=id)
                #Beginning of Pet Policy Instances 
                user_floor_plan = FloorPlan.objects.select_related('Property').filter(property_name=user_property)
                if user_floor_plan:
                    print user_floor_plan
                    plans = user_floor_plan.count()
                    plans = plans + 1
                    FloorPlanFormset = inlineformset_factory(Property, FloorPlan, num=plans)
                    formset_floor_plan = FloorPlanFormset(instance=user_floor_plan)
                    print "formset_floor_plan is True"
                else:
                    floor_plan_form = FloorPlanForm(request.POST or None)
                    formset_floor_plan = False
                    print 'formset is %s' % (formset_floor_plan)
                #End
                #Beginning of Pet Policy Instances 
                user_pet_policy = PetPolicy.objects.select_related('Property').filter(property_name=user_property)
                print user_pet_policy
                if user_pet_policy:
                    print user_pet_policy
                    #pet_policy_form = PetPolicyForm(request.POST or None, instance=user_pet_policy)
                    pet_policy_form = PetPolicyForm(request.POST or None)
                else:
                    pet_policy_form = PetPolicyForm(request.POST or None)
                #End
                basic_form = PropertyForm(request.POST or None, instance=user_property)
                context = {
                'user_property': user_property,
                'basic_form': basic_form,
                'floor_plan_form': floor_plan_form,
                'formset_floor_plan': formset_floor_plan,
                'pet_policy_form': pet_policy_form,
                }
                template = 'dashboard/dashboard_single_property.html'
                return render(request, template, context)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        except:
            #raise Http404
            print "whoops"
        #RETURN SOMETHING HERE ! ! !
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
```